# Safari isn't sending XMLHTTPRequest cookies at random

Tags: express, safari, xmlhttprequest, passport.js, express-session

I have an Express server using PassportJS authentication. I am using standard XMLHTTPRequests to retrieve files.

Chrome and Firefox work without problems. Safari (Mac and iOS) is failing to send a request cookie with some requests and doing this inconsistently.

Logged failed requests all have a different session id that isn't authenticated with PassportJS.

Chrome and Firefox have a single session id for all requests.

I'm not using cross-origin requests, these are all same-origin. I have tried using withCredentials true with the same result but this property shouldn't be needed anyway as it's same-origin and Chrome and Firefox work without it.

There doesn't seem to be a pattern to which files fail to send the request cookie. Sometimes at random (but rarely), all requests load ok.

It's not a sequential failure, most requests succeed to begin with then a sequence of fails with some successes in between.

The Express server isn't destroying the sessions, they keep accumulating. Failed requests have session ids that are not authenticated sessions.

What would cause Safari to randomly not send the request cookie for some XMLHTTPRequests?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be the crossOrigin property, I must have been doing cross-origin requests:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes

Most of my loaded files had their crossOrigin property set as "anonymous". For some reason, Chrome and Firefox seemed to ignore this and sent the cookie credentials anyway but Safari didn't. Setting this property to "use-credentials" worked fine:

img.crossOrigin = "use-credentials";